# Как сделать правильное отображение иконок «открыт/закрыт» аккордеона на jQuery?

Tags: javascript, css, jquery, wordpress

У есть код аккордеона на jQuery для WordPress

```js
jQuery(function($){
  var buttons = {
  '.rv_button_1': {
    'toggle': '.rv_element_1', 
    'hide'  : '.rv_element_2,.rv_element_3', 
    'show'  : ''
  },
  '.rv_button_2': {
    'toggle': '.rv_element_2', 
    'hide'  : '.rv_element_1,.rv_element_3', 
    'show'  : ''
  },
  '.rv_button_3': {
    'toggle': '.rv_element_3', 
    'hide'  : '.rv_element_1,.rv_element_2', 
    'show'  : ''
  }
};
  $.each(buttons, function(button, elements) {
    $(button).click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $(elements.toggle).slideToggle();
      $(elements.show).slideDown();
      $(elements.hide).slideUp();
      $(button).toggleClass('rv_button_opened rv_button_closed');
    });
  });
});
```

```css
body:not(.et-fb) .show-on-click, 
body:not(.et-fb) .toggle-on-click,
body:not(.et-fb) .rv_element { 
  display: none; 
}


.rv_button_opened:after { 
  z-index: 999 ;
  content: '\21' ;
  color: #c9c9c9 ;
font-size: 16px ;
  }
.rv_button_closed:after { 
  z-index: 999 ;
  content:"\4c" ;
  color: #FF6600 ;
font-weight: normal ;
font-size: 16px ;
}
```

Каждой кнопке присвоен класс : rv_button_1 rv_button_closed ; rv_button_2 rv_button_closed и т.д.
Да скрываемой секции присвоен класс : rv_element rv_element_1 ; rv_element rv_element_2 и т.д.

Проблема в том что при открытой №1 секции и нажатии на другую секцию : секция №1 закрывается, а иконка этой секции остается прежней (не меняется на иконку "закрыт")

Необходимо чтобы когда секция закрыта показывалась иконка "закрыт", а когда открыта показывалась иконка "открыт"

вот фото
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Стрела вверх это иконка "открыт"
Плюс это "закрыт"
Как видно из фото - там где секция ESSENTIALS закрыта отображается не та иконка , как и в случае с открытой секции FINAL TOUCHES

Проблема заключается (на сколько я понимаю) в этом

```js
$(button).toggleClass('rv_button_opened rv_button_closed');
```

То есть к открытым кнопкам добавляются не классы rv_button_opened , а к закрытым наоборот
И в следствии этого происходит путаница иконок

Пробовала вот так сделать

```js
$.each(buttons, function(button, elements) {
    $(button).click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $(elements.toggle).slideToggle();
      $(elements.show).slideDown();
      $(elements.hide).slideUp();
      $(this).toggleClass('rv_button_opened');
$(buttons).not(this).removeClass('rv_button_opened');
    });
  });
```

Ни чего не помогло - теперь что открыт или закрыт = везде одни "плюс"

Comment: Добавьте html дабы пример был воспроизводим

Comment: к сожалению я верстать еще не умею. А этот код я использую в готовой теме Divi.
Я нашла его  [здесь](https://divibooster.com/reveal-a-divi-module-or-row-section-when-button-clicked/)

Comment: В строке `$(this).toggleClass('rv_button_opened');` вы меняете класс ..opened а где вы убираете класс `.rv_button_closed` вообще для таких действий нужен один класс, к примеру `.js-is-opened` который будет разворачивать пункт, если класса нет то по умолчанию свернуто. js в начале класса чтоб было понятно что этим классом управляет js, так удобней самому потом рабоать

Comment: В css у вас вначале написано `.rv_button_opened` потом `.rv_button_closed` специфичность у них одинакова, по этому пока вы не уберете closed он будет перекрывать стили opened